# R: group by and count proportions in column with strings/lists

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

(Edit: The data tags are not always multiples of three)
Consider data as follows:

```
some_tags <- c("cat|hat", 
               "cat|hat|hog", 
               "cat|bat",
               "bat|hat|dog",
               "rat")
set.seed(2)
data.frame(clusters=sample.int(3, 5,replace = T),
           tag=some_tags)
```

The resulting dataframe is

```
  clusters         tag
1        1     cat|hat
2        3 cat|hat|hog
3        2     cat|bat
4        1 bat|hat|dog
5        3         rat
```

I'd like to do a group by on clusters that gives me the proportion of times a "tag" (separated by a vertical bar) shows up in that cluster. e.g. the following would be the desired result

```
clusters    tag     prop
        1   hat      1.0
        1   dog      0.5
        1   cat      0.5
        1   bat      0.5
        2   cat      1.0
        2   bat      1.0
... (cluster 3 results not shown)
```

I was considering doing something like `strsplit` and `table` but don't know if there's a simpler way to do this with dplyr.

Comment: Can you explain why you get the numbers you have? E.g. cluster 1 has cat once, hat twice, dog twice, bat once. So I would expect 0.167 for cat and bat but 0.333 for hat and dog. Instead you have 1.0 and 0.5. Do you just want to multiply by 3?

Comment: two observations in cluster 1. cat once in cluster 1 gives a frequency of 1/2. dog is there twice so 2/2 =1.0

Comment: I'm not getting the same example data.frame now.

Comment: @ngm just fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse`, illustrating some of the ways you can use different group counts to get the result you want. `add_count` tells us how many rows there are in each cluster, `separate_rows` splits each row into three, so each tag has its own row; then we can `group_by` both `cluster` and `tag` and use `n()` to tell us how many of each tag there are in each cluster, and divide by the total tags per cluster to get a proportion. We have to use `first` because this is inside a `summarise` call and otherwise we'd be making a vector that is too long.

```r
df <- structure(list(clusters = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), tag = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("bat|hat|dog", "cat|bat|dog", "cat|hat|dog", "cat|hat|hog", "rat|mat|hog"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  add_count(clusters) %>%
  separate_rows(tag, sep = "\\|") %>%
  group_by(clusters, tag) %>%
  summarise(prop = first(n()) / first(n))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   clusters [?]
#>    clusters tag    prop
#>       <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1        1 bat     0.5
#>  2        1 cat     0.5
#>  3        1 dog     1  
#>  4        1 hat     1  
#>  5        2 bat     1  
#>  6        2 cat     1  
#>  7        2 dog     1  
#>  8        3 cat     0.5
#>  9        3 hat     0.5
#> 10        3 hog     1  
#> 11        3 mat     0.5
#> 12        3 rat     0.5
```

Created on 2018-06-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: fyi the tags might be of varying length e.g. "cat" might be in one row, and "hat|dog|chicken" in another.

Comment: ok, fixed to address that, though you should also update your example data and desired output to reflect this situation.